# Importing C libraries into eclipse through plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have build up a C library using my C source code and I have the lib file ready.

Now I want to import this lib file to my eclipse through eclipse plugin.

I want to develop a eclipse plugin which includes these lib files such that I can use my old source codes over here in eclipse just like android plugin for app developers which contains android source code.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse it's just an IDE, C and C++ support for development purposes are provided by other packages or plugins if you will, the most popular one is [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php).

You can install cdt by simply using the Help menu in your Eclipse.

But in my experience Eclipse is probably one of the worst IDE for development, the C and C++ situation is even worst.